# Java Web Service lock static value

Tags: java, web-services, static

I have web service ws for bankomats, there are two method only get and block  part of my code:

```
   @WebService(endpointInterface= "foo..", targetNamespace="goo..")
   public class ATMServiceImpl implements ATMService {

    static String pan = "";
    static int amount = 0;
    public GetResponse get(GetRequest body) throws PaymentServerFault {
        pan = getMd5....
        amount += addMoneyFromUserType()....
    }

     public GetResponse block(GetRequest body) throws PaymentServerFault {
      // here i want use this pan and amount

    }


   }
```

Every bankomats come on this service,

this works only for one bankomats, but when different users use other bankomats it's bad idea because of static... how i can manage this for only one user use amount and other users use another amount, can anyone explain me how it work in Soap service ?  after calling block method i do `amount = 0;`  maybe in this moment someone use other bankomats and i change this value it bad idea too..